# Find the value of $p_{2021}$.

Tags: contest-math

Given a sequence $\{i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. A new sequence $\{p_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is obtained from $\{i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ by omitting all multiples of $3$ or $4$, but not $5$. Find $p_{2021}$.

I try as follows.

Let $S=\{1, 2, 3, ...,2021\}$.

Let $A=\{3, 6, 9, ..., 2019\}$, $B=\{4, 8, 12,..., 2020\}$, $C=\{60, 120, 180,..., 1980\}$,
then

$|A|=673$, $|B|=505$. $|C|=33$

The number of omitted is $|S|-|A|-|B|+|C|=2021-673-505+33=876$
$p_{2021}=2021+|S|-|A|-|B|+|C|=2021+2021-673-505+33=2897$.

I'm very not sure with my answer. Anyone can help me?

Comment: in additional 876 numbers, there will be some multiples of 3 and 4 which are to be omitted. (And the calculation of the number 876 is wrong too. for example the number 12 is considered twice)

Comment: My suggestion is: the sequence is periodic, i.e. if $a$ is in the sequence then $a+60$ also is, where the number 60 is the least common multiple of 3, 4, 5. Justify this and try to use this fact

Comment: You've tagged this as *contest-math* -- could you specify which contest and confirm that it's not ongoing please?

Comment: This is only exercise for math contest.

Answer (score 1):

Let's count how many of the first $60n$ numbers satisfy these conditions.

Out of the first $60n$ numbers, there are $20n$ multiples of $3$; there are $15n$ multiples of $4$; there are $4n$ multiples of $15$; there are $3n$ multiples of $20$, and there are $n$ multiples of $60$.

Now consider the inequality  $$60n-20n-15n+4n+5n+3n-n\geq 2021$$
$$36n\geq 2021$$
$$n>56.13888$$

$$60n>3368.33$$

This is also confirmed by the following simple Python code.

> ```
> l=[]
>
> for i in range(1,5000):
>     l.append(i)
>     
>     
> for i in range(1,5000):
>     if (i%3==0 or i%4==0) and i%5!=0:
>         l.remove(i)
>         
>         
> print(l[2020])
> ```

$$p_{2021}=3370$$

You can run this code [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler).

Comment: FYI You can edit your own solution if there is additional/different information that you want to showcase. Generally only add another solution is it's significantly different (EG Running code vs Counting argument)